# Total Laws of Probability, Music Festival Question

Tags: probability

Question: Katia is going to a music festival which takes place over two days. She will feel that the festival was worth it only if she sees Beyoncé on either day. But Katia has only a 10% chance of getting tickets on the first day, and a 5% chance on the second day. She’ll try to get tickets on both days, unless she manages to get a ticket on the first day (in which case she won’t try again). What are the chances that Katia will end up feeling like the festival was worth it?

My solution:
So whether she tries to go to the second is not independent of whether she goes to the first

Pr(First day):0.1
Pr(~First day):0.9
Pr(Second day):0.05
Pr(~Second day): 0.95

can someone assist me for setting up the equation.

I know the question is asking whether Katia feels like the festival was worth it depends if she see beyonce

so Pr(Worth it | beyonce) = ? (not sure how this will work out since I dont have the chances of this happening)

am I on the right track or im off?

Comment: I think, based on the question, getting a ticket means she will see Beyonce

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get a ticket on either day, she must either get it on the first day or not get it the first day but then get it on the second day.

The probability of getting it on the first day is $0.1$

The probability of not getting it on the first day but then getting it on the second day is $(1-0.1)\cdot0.05=0.045$

Thus the desired probability is $$0.1+0.045=0.145$$

Alternatively we can find the compliment of not getting a ticket on either day

$$1-(0.9\cdot0.95)=0.145$$

Comment: I know this is a dumb question but what is the overall question of this question? lol Are we looking for if Katia thinks the festival was worth it or the probability of getting the tickets

Comment: The two are synonymous

Comment: oh I see thanks for your help remy and plus on my other two questions!! I have a midterm coming up this week and you been very helpful

Comment: You're welcome and good luck!